# how to get rid of color values on .svg file? (paint by number)

Tags: python, svg, computer-vision

I have few .svg files that I played around to make a paint by color few years ago (I lost the project that used to be open source). Recently, I digged it back and now I want to get rid of all colors, leaving just the white background, black lines, and number labels (just like the coloring book). I tried simple python code to delete the "fill" and "stroke" value, but did not turn out so well. Guess my approach is too simple and inefficient.

This is the sample .svg file: [Google drive share](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RjxjOtBOfLUJGm5bK7irAlXmdyPrrbn2/view?usp=sharing)

Below is what I tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

svg_file = ET.parse('test1.svg')
root = svg_file.getroot()

for elem in root.iter():
    if 'fill' in elem.attrib:
        del elem.attrib['fill']
    if 'stroke' in elem.attrib:
        del elem.attrib['stroke']

svg_file.write('test1_1.svg')
```

Comment: Don't delete them, set them to white and black.

Comment: I actually tried but did not turn out so well.

Comment: Have you inspected the file? Fills and strokes are set via style declaration- so trying to find and replace attributes won't work. Just do a regex replace for fill: rgb(X) with fill: rgb(255,255,255). Don't touch the stroke - it's already set to 1px black.

Answer (score 0):

So my .svg file was used below to control the fill colors.

```
style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1px; fill: rgb(0, 160, 232)
```

And, this is to control the color of the text.

```
text font-family="Tahoma" font-size="50" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000"
```

So I simply changed RBG values to white only while keeping #000 using the below command:

```
updated_svg_data = re.sub(r'fill:.*?rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\);(?!.*fill:\s*#000)', r'fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);', svg_data)
```

And it worked out well :)